# Does MySQL still issues deadlock errors when using IGNORE in a query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-deadlocks

I've used `IGNORE` before in `mysql` queries and I generally use this to avoid `mysql` returning errors when you try and insert a `duplicate key`, however I am not sure how this works - does mysql just ignore errors when using `IGNORE` or does it only ignore the `duplicate key` error?

So, for example, if a `deadlock` occurred would it still issue the error when using `IGNORE` in the query?

**Edit:**

Doing some more reading and found this info:

> If you use the IGNORE keyword, **errors that occur while executing the INSERT statement are ignored.** For example, without IGNORE, a row that duplicates an existing UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY value in the table causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is aborted. With IGNORE, the row is discarded and no error occurs. Ignored errors may generate warnings instead, although duplicate-key errors do not.

Well I guess that mean deadlock errors only will generate warnings then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IGNORE` keyword only ignores duplicate key errors and these rows with duplicate keys will not be inserted but other rows without the error do. Warning will be generated.

In case of **concurrent** `INSERT` if some other thread has locked the set of "unique values" then your thread will wait for the lock to release and give deadlock/lock wait timeout exceeded error. 
In this case no rows will be inserted (of that statement) and ERROR is returned

Have table:

```
CREATE TABLE `t` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Now run these 2 queries at the same time:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO t(id)
VALUES (5+sleep(1)),(6+sleep(1)),(3+sleep(1)),(4+sleep(1));
/* Affected rows: 4  Found rows: 0  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 4,586 sec. */

INSERT IGNORE INTO t(id)
VALUES (3+sleep(1)),(4+sleep(1)),(5+sleep(1)),(6+sleep(1));
/* SQL Error (1213): Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction */
/* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 0  Warnings: 0  Duration for 0 of 1 query: 0,000 sec. */
```

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood my question - I found some info and edited it at the same time of your answer.

Comment: updated  the answer, deadlock errors are still errors

Comment: Well, they may be errors but doesn't my quote indicate that when using `IGNORE` it will not return any errors, only *warnings*.

Comment: It will only ignore **duplicate key** error. In case of deadlock there is a concurrency issue that mysql engine cant decide which one of the rows being inserted it should ignore (because neither is commited yet).

Comment: I think that is wrong because *Ignored errors may generate warnings instead, although duplicate-key errors do not. * -- meaning that errors generate warnings instead of errors, but duplicate-key errors generate nothing. At least that is how I understood it.

Comment: For example I just ran a test with trying to insert a NULL value whilst using IGNORE and it only returned a warning, not an error. Syntax errors still get returned though.

Comment: in case of `NULL` it converts it to `0` if column is `NOT NULL`

Comment: How do you run them at the same time? I'm using `SQLYog` and I tried using the "run all queries" option but didn't get any deadlocks.

Comment: you need to have 2 instances of SQLYog active. run 1st query in one,  2nd in other and wait both queries to end. also be sure there is no such id-s already

Comment: That doesn't quite work, by the time I mouse over to the second instance to run it it gives me a "duplicate key error".

Comment: Ok, found the issue. I need to do `START TRANSACTION` before the queries you provided and then `COMMIT` after. I have now seen it still outputs an error for deadlocks.